# Customize twitter typeahead dropdown template

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

Hi guys,

I'm using twitter's typeahead.js to implement an autocomplete function for my search box.

I know I can set headers for different sections like in the NBA and NHL teams example here http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

however, this is for multiple data source. I was wondering what if my data source is single but the items returned are in different categories

for example, if I type in something, the search function will search through all the categories and return whatever it found in every categories, perhaps in random order like:

itemA-category1
itemB-category1
itemC-category2
itemD-category3
itemE-category1

How can I still display something like below in the dropdown menu?

Category1 // this is just a header 
ItemA 
ItemB
ItemE
Category2
ItemC
Category3
ItemD

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You could create separate queries which would in turn create separate json files. You could then search each of these json files collectively. What have you tried so far?